# Send Email to Task owners as long as task is not complete and Project is not backlogged

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script below, that emails the person a copy of all of their assigned tasks that are not complete.
**However, I would like it to skip all Tasks where the Main Projects status is "backlog"**
Here is my current code, and a link to a copy of the tables:

```
function sendEmails() {

  // Retrieve Project IDs, Project names and Project Status
 const project = sheetITPM.getRange("A2:J" + sheetITPM.getLastRow()).getValues().map(r => ({ id: r[0], name: r[1],  status: r[2]}));

//get Tasks Sheet and all rows needed
  let s = '';
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ITPM_Tasks");
  const lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  const startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  const numRows = lastRow - 1; // Number of rows to process
  const rg = sh.getRange(startRow, 3, numRows, 6);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  let oners = {pA:[]};

  //function to NOT include projects with status: "backlog"

  //dont include tasks with status "Complete"
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let [name,desc,status,owner,due] = r;
    if(status != 'Complete') {
     if(!oners.hasOwnProperty(owner)) {
       oners[owner]=[];
       oners[owner].push(r);
       oners.pA.push(owner)
     } else {
       oners[owner].push(r);
     }
    }
  });

//email subject and start message
  let subject = 'IT Board - Weekly Reminder: The following tasks are assigned to you.';
  oners.pA.forEach(p => {
     let msg = `These Tasks below are assigned to you:\n`

//task array 
    oners[p].forEach((r,i) => {
      let [name,desc,status,owner,due] = r;
        msg += `Task - ${i+1}\n`;
        msg += `Description: ${desc}\n`;
        msg += `Due Date: ${due}\n\n`
    });

    msg += `notify the IT Project Management Team of any updates\n\nThank You`;
    
    //send email to the task owner with their task array + subject + our message 
    MailApp.sendEmail(oners[p][0][3], subject, msg);
  });
}
```

Link to sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGojtDy9sDpGexiT_ixF_H_95GG_uiYeAkNUWzYkKSE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is keeping you from making the modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting the list of IDs for backlog projects first and then using `includes` to check if the project name of the task belongs to the list of IDs. See code below:

#### Script:

```
  let oners = {pA:[]};

  // get backlog projects, then create an array containing the ids of those projects
  const backlogProjects = project.filter(x => x.status == 'Backlog').map(x => x.id);

  // dont include tasks with status "Complete"
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let [name,desc,status,owner,due] = r;
    // check if project name matches the IDs present in the generated array above
    if(status != 'Complete' && !backlogProjects.includes(name)) {
     if(!oners.hasOwnProperty(owner)) {
       oners[owner]=[];
       oners[owner].push(r);
       oners.pA.push(owner)
     } else {
       oners[owner].push(r);
     }
    }
  });
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Output shows no `nl7k28t` in the tasks as that project is still in Backlog status.